# MAMP Pro /MAMP/ start page not accessible on local network

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I am trying to access the MAMP Pro /MAMP/ start page over the local network, but I get the following error in the apache log:

```
[Wed Feb 24 12:21:03 2016] [error] [client 192.168.1.63] client denied by server configuration: /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/mamp
```

I have locally mapped http://dev in my host file to the ip of the server, and I *am* able to view the websites hosted by MAMP, but not the start page.

Some facts that may be of use to diagnose:

- I am using MAMP Pro 3.5
- The document root has been changed to ~/Sites
- If I run normal MAMP I can access the start page fine from the local
  network. This is using the same ports as MAMP Pro, the same
  document root, and the same PHP version.

I am under the impression that for some reason MAMP Pro uses a different location for the mamp start page files than that of MAMP? I have found the files in:

```
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/mamp
```

and

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp
```

and the permissions seem to be the same, as is the user.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PeterInWiesbaden's answer was helpful in pointing me in the right direction. The issue was that in my (normal) MAMP httpd.conf file I had set all the paths of the MAMP start files to be similar to the following:

```
Alias /MAMP "/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp"

<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

but when I edited them in the httpd.conf file directly used by MAMP Pro, these get overwritten each time the server starts, as it uses a template for each Server Name.

To edit httpd.conf for MAMP Pro, it must be done through going to the following in the menu bar:

```
File->Edit Template->Apache->httpd.conf
```

And changing the MAMP Pro start pages sections similar to the following:

```
Alias /MAMP "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/mamp"

<Directory "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/mamp">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: To add a bit more to this. If you don't want it to be accessible to *everyone* you can just change it to: `Alias /MAMP "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/mamp"
 
 <Directory "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/mamp">
  Options Indexes
  AllowOverride None
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from localhost
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  Allow from ::1
  Allow from 192.168
 </Directory>` where 192.168 allows all IPs starting with 192.168

Answer (score 2):

Had this in the past, just use IP address of the MAMP Mac.

Sometimes I had to configure the Apache http settings and set my other local IP address in to the ALLOW part.

Greetings,
Peter